# mysql2 gem crashes randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I am in the process to upgrade our application to Rails 5.
I have upgraded to ruby 2.4.5 then all the gems in our gemfile with Rails 5.2.2. The mysql2 gem is 0.5.2.
I am running our tests and I have randomly Mysql2::Error

```
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:45:in `affected_rows'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:45:in `block in exec_delete'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:196:in `execute_and_free'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:45:in `exec_delete'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:168:in `delete'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:21:in `delete'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:409:in `delete_all'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/querying.rb:10:in `delete_all'
```

Another Mysql2 error:

```
Failure/Error: _query(sql, @query_options.merge(options))

 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: MySQL server has gone away: BEGIN
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:131:in `_query'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:131:in `block in query'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:130:in `handle_interrupt'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:130:in `query'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:187:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:186:in `block in execute'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in log'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:578:in `block in log'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:569:in `log'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:185:in `execute'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:28:in `execute'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:200:in `begin_db_transaction'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:175:in `initialize'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:201:in `new'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:201:in `block in begin_transaction'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:197:in `begin_transaction'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:267:in `begin_transaction'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:975:in `block in setup_fixtures'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:974:in `each'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:974:in `setup_fixtures'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:860:in `before_setup'
 # ------------------
 # --- Caused by: ---
 # Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError:
 #   MySQL server has gone away
 #   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:131:in `_query'
```

Then re-running the same tests I have some malloc crash:

```
ruby(73560,0x70000d9c0000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9bdb234000: pointer being freed was not allocated
ruby(73560,0x70000d9c0000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Then re-running the tests, sometimes I have a SEG fault:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@clm/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:131: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0xffffffffffffffe1
ruby 2.4.5p335 (2018-10-18 revision 65137) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

But I never have my tests running properly and it never happens on the same place. The same tests are running perfectly on Ruby 2.2.9, Rails 4.2.8 with mysql2 0.4.10.
It has been several days that I am trying to google the issue without success. The versions are not that recent and I don't see where is the issue. I tried to uninstall mysql2, then re-install it.
I have mysql 5.7 installed on my mac. I am on Mac OS 10.14.2.

Please advise.

Comment: "Server has gone away" happens when you have a stale connection or the server has restarted somehow. Anything that results in a hard-crash is a bug in the gem or Ruby, but I'd file a bug report with the [`mysql2` project](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues) unless this has been reported previously.

Comment: Do you have a hard requirement for that version? Can you try Ruby 2.6.0? Or 2.5.3?

Comment: Well I tried ruby 2.5.3 and it is even worst. Unfortunately I cannot go above as it won't be possible to install it in production....
Thanks for the comments I am going to try to file a bug like you suggest.

Comment: @Stephanie were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: I actually found the root cause of the issue. In Rails 5 the callbacks are running and we had callbacks that were launching asynchronous jobs. In our tests I made sure the jobs were not running.
I have to create a gist as I have reproduced the issue on a simple project. I understand that it cannot run in the tests but it should not crash like that....

Comment: @Stephanie you're right, it's about asynchronous jobs in tests, adding ```include ActiveJob::TestHelper ;  after { clear_enqueued_jobs }``` here or there, or even mocking jobs in some tests helps.